# Jenkins stops responding when building android project

Tags: android, maven, build, jenkins

I can't figure out why Jenkins stops responding (and I end up having to restart the Jenkins service) when I try to build an Android project.

I'm new to this so I'm not sure what information would be useful to debug the issue, but I'd be happy to provide whatever's needed.

Not sure if this is relevant, but when I restart the Jenkins service, I see the build that failed is missing in Jenkins build history.

Weird thing is I can run the build directly (as jenkins) from the command line with no issues.  All I have to do is set environment variables for ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME, then run

```
mvn clean install.
```

I'm running Jenkins on a headless Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.

When it stalls, the last bit in Jenkins console output is:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------
     T E S T S
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Running TestSuite
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.793 sec

    Results :

    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:emma (default-emma) @ application ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:dex (default-dex) @ application ---
    [INFO] /var/lib/jenkins/tools/JDK/jdk-6/jre/bin/java [-Xmx1024M, -jar, /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar, --dex, --output=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moodsherpa/workspace/android/application/target/classes.dex, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/moodsherpa/workspace/android/application/target/classes, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/actionbarsherlock/library/4.0.2/library-4.0.2.apklib, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/commonsware/cwac-loaderex/0.3.0/cwac-loaderex-0.3.0.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/3.0/guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/roboguice/roboguice/2.0/roboguice-2.0.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/android/support-v4/r7/support-v4-r7.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar]
    Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Using the Maven -X flag:

```
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:dex (default-dex) @ application ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:dex from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.2.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@77cde100]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:dex' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) aaptExtraArgs = []
[DEBUG]   (f) androidManifestFile = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/AndroidManifest.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) assetsDirectory = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/assets
[DEBUG]   (f) attachJar = true
[DEBUG]   (f) attachSources = false
[DEBUG]   (f) combinedAssets = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/generated-sources/combined-assets/assets
[DEBUG]   (f) combinedRes = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/generated-sources/combined-resources/res
[DEBUG]   (f) dexCoreLibrary = false
[DEBUG]   (f) dexJvmArguments = [-Xmx1024M]
[DEBUG]   (f) dexNoLocals = false
[DEBUG]   (f) dexOptimize = true
[DEBUG]   (f) envANDROID_HOME = /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/
[DEBUG]   (f) extractedDependenciesAssets = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/generated-sources/extracted-dependencies/assets
[DEBUG]   (f) extractedDependenciesDirectory = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/generated-sources/extracted-dependencies
[DEBUG]   (f) extractedDependenciesJavaResources = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/generated-sources/extracted-dependencies/src/main/resources
[DEBUG]   (f) extractedDependenciesJavaSources = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/generated-sources/extracted-dependencies/src/main/java
[DEBUG]   (f) extractedDependenciesRes = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/generated-sources/extracted-dependencies/res
[DEBUG]   (f) generateApk = true
[DEBUG]   (f) nativeLibrariesDirectory = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/libs
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.ms.android:application:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) projectRepos = [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG]   (f) repoSession = org.sonatype.aether.util.DefaultRepositorySystemSession@566e9e64
[DEBUG]   (f) resourceDirectory = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/res
[DEBUG]   (f) resourceOverlayDirectory = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/res-overlay
[DEBUG]   (f) platform = 15
[DEBUG]   (f) sdk = com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.configuration.Sdk@1f26ecd2
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@29eb0cd0
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceDirectory = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/src/main/java
[DEBUG]   (f) undeployBeforeDeploy = true
[DEBUG]   (f) unpackedApkLibsDirectory = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/unpack/apklibs
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Checking for existence of: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/proguard-obfuscated.jar
[DEBUG] Using non-obfuscated input
[DEBUG] Adding jvm argument -Xmx1024M
[DEBUG] Adding dex input: /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
[DEBUG] Adding dex input: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/classes
[DEBUG] Adding dex input: /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/actionbarsherlock/library/4.0.2/library-4.0.2.apklib
[DEBUG] Adding dex input: /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/commonsware/cwac-loaderex/0.3.0/cwac-loaderex-0.3.0.jar
[DEBUG] Adding dex input: /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/3.0/guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar
[DEBUG] Adding dex input: /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar
[DEBUG] Adding dex input: /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/roboguice/roboguice/2.0/roboguice-2.0.jar
[DEBUG] Adding dex input: /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/android/support-v4/r7/support-v4-r7.jar
[DEBUG] Adding dex input: /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[INFO] /var/lib/jenkins/tools/JDK/jdk-6/jre/bin/java [-Xmx1024M, -jar, /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar, --dex, --output=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/classes.dex, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ms/workspace/android/application/target/classes, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/actionbarsherlock/library/4.0.2/library-4.0.2.apklib, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/commonsware/cwac-loaderex/0.3.0/cwac-loaderex-0.3.0.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/3.0/guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/roboguice/roboguice/2.0/roboguice-2.0.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/android/support-v4/r7/support-v4-r7.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar]
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded from 512 to 2048MB of RAM and that solved my problem.